# Change element color based on scroll position using Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this ul arrangement:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
<li class="post red"></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.post{height:80px;width:300px;border:1px solid green;}
```

I want the `li` change of background color after the scroll passes at its level....

I tried this but nothing

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    

 if($(window).ScrollTop == $(this).offset().top){
         $(".post").toggleClass("red blue");//prior add
        $(this).addClass("blue");
 }

});
```

I am not into working with `#id` because I wouldnt know how to handle it, My page has a complex arrangment with no Id configuration

this is a non-working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uawLLvfx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the li change of background color after the scroll passes at its level....

use `scrollTop()` function, not ".ScrollTop"

```js
let $w = $(window), lis = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
$w.scroll(function() {    
   lis.forEach(function (li) {
      let $li = $(li);
      if($w.scrollTop()+ $li.outerHeight() >= $li.offset().top) {
          $li.addClass("blue")
             .siblings().removeClass('blue')
      }
   })

});
```

```css
.red{background-color:red}
.blue{background-color:blue}
li{min-height: 100px; margin-top: 15px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="post red">Test1</li>
<li class="post red">Test2</li>
<li class="post red">Test3</li>
<li class="post red">Test4</li>
<li class="post red">Test5</li>
<li class="post red">Test6</li>
<li class="post red">Test7</li>
<li class="post red">Test8</li>
<li class="post red">Test9</li>
<li class="post red">Test10</li>
<li class="post red">Test11</li>
<li class="post red">Test12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works awesome, thank you. you are using all the `li` found on thew page....In my page I have several li arrangement, How do I select from an specific `ul`? for example `ul#menu`

Comment: See the `document.querySelectorAll('li')` at the top of the code ? Simply replace `'li'`with the appropriate selector, `'ul#menu li'` I guess.